# How do you make hunger go down in minecraft but without monsters spawning?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to make a Hunger Games LAN world, but I keep getting killed by mobs.  I want hunger to diminish, but to prevent monsters from spawning. Is there a command for that? If there is, what is it?

Comment: Welcome to the ArQAde. Your question is difficult to understand, could you please edit in some details and grammar? Do you mean you want a monster free world (as in creative mode) but still be hungry (as in survival mode)?

Comment: @Zommuter Player being in Creative mode has no impact on world, monsters still do spawn. You probably meant Peaceful difficulty.

Comment: @OrcJMR I was thinking about the godmode-ish behaviour of creative, but you're right, peaceful describes it better

Comment: I dont feel this should be closed.

Comment: @Ender It probably won't be since the edit. It wasn't even closeable before though, just badly written—some people must still be abusing close-votes as super-downvotes.

Comment: Make the game mode peaceful. That should take care of the mobs

Answer (score 21):

If you have cheats enabled, you can do the following:

1. Make sure the difficulty is set to Easy or higher.
2. Type in the command: `/gamerule doMobSpawning false`. (This is case sensitive!)

Now monsters will no longer spawn, but you will still get hungry. This works because, when you set `doMobSpawning` to false it prevents monsters from ever spawning, and when you set the difficulty to anything other than Peaceful you get hungry.

Monsters will still spawn using Spawn Eggs or from Mob Spawners (including those naturally generated in dungeons), but they will not naturally spawn.

Source: [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands)

Comment: why dose it say no such gamerule noMobspawn?

Comment: @aba It's doMobSpawning with a 'd'.

Comment: It's also case sensitive.

Comment: Wouldn't this prevent spawning of peaceful creatures as well?